# How do I disable toggle button?

Tags: html, angular

I want to display toggle button in HTML with disabled.

My button code:

```
<td >
    <div class="toggle" [class.on]="isActive" (click)="function(no)">
    <div class="toggle-btn"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

I've tried to put `disabled`:

```
<div class="toggle" [class.on]="isActive" (click)="function(no) disabled">
```

And:

```
<div class="toggle-btn" disabled></div>
```

But it doesn't work. Any solutions?

Comment: It's a **toggle** button - not a "toogle" button ...

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found own solution by just adding CSS

> pointer-events:none

Answer (score 2):

Use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) in html:

```
<button type="button" [ngClass]="{'disabled-btn': isDisabled}">Submit</button>
```

ts file, manage isDisabled variable:

```
this.isDisabled = true;
```

in css, adding style to disabled-btn class:

```
.disabled-btn {
      pointer-events: none;
      opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the html `<button>` instead of `<div>`, as the `disabled` attribute is available on the button tag. You can even bind the disabled attribute.

```
<button type="button" class="toggle" (click)="function(no)" [disabled]="isDisabled">Submit</button>
```

On your component.ts, you can simple toggle the disabled attribute by setting it to `true` or `false`.

```
this.isDisabled = true; // disables button
```

Alternatively, if you are planning to bind the `disabled` attribute to any properties, you can still dynamically disable the button by using [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the element, and then set the disabled attribute to true.

```
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
button['disabled'] = true;
```

Comment: It doesn't show like a toogle anymore , just a button instead

Comment: @hatched Actually, I am confused by your question. Is that supposed to be a button, or a toggle switch?

Comment: its a toogle switch

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="true">Submit</button >
```